# Is it safe to use the SHFileOperation in a worker thread?

Tags: delphi, winapi, thread-safety, windows-shell, shfileoperation

I would like to have

- one background thread which will copy the files through the `SHFileOperation` function, always only one `SHFileOperation` at the time (but I want it to be in the thread)
- I need the UI output, so I need to use the `FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS` flag and pass something to the `Wnd` member

I have two questions

1. is it safe to call the `SHFileOperation` with `FOF_SIMPLEPROGRESS` flag (for user interaction) from the thread other than main ?
2. if yes, what handle should I pass into the `Wnd` member ? I've tried the handle of the main form, but when e.g. the overwrite confirmation dialog pops up and you confirm it, the main form is sent to the background, what is really strange

Note:
I have a queue for these operations, so only one `SHFileOperation` is performed at the time (after it's finished, the thread continues to the other action, what might be the next `SHFileOperation`)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. It's perfectly safe to call `SHFileOperation` from a thread other than the main thread.
2. I would pass `0` as the `hwnd` member. If you pass the handle of the main window then I expect that window will be disabled because `SHFileOperation` is a modal dialog. Since the file confirmation and progress dialogs are the top level UI for the background thread, you don't want any windows to be disabled when these modal dialogs show.

Comment: Great to hear this. `Wnd` member set to 0 works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also, the documentation also mentions that using relative paths with SHFILEOPSTRUCT is NOT thread safe.  So if your using this in a worker thread you must use absolute paths!

Comment: @8bitwide Using relative paths is never thread safe. Not for any API call. That's because there's one working directory per process.